# How to schedule Gitlab build/deployment for one app in a mono repo

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

We have a large mono repo containing several individual apps, each with their own `.gitlab-ci.yml` files. They all have this rule defined:

```
.change-only:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master" && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE != "schedule"
```

Is it possible to define a schedule for just one of these apps to run at a particular time, without triggering all the rest?

If I try to create a new scheduled pipeline in the Gitlab, I can only choose which branch and not the individual apps that all live in the same master branch. I don't want to schedule all of them at 8:00 am, for example - just one.

Answer (score 1):

Well I have done something like this maybe it will help for you too. As Mono repos if you have multiple apps make a unique placeholder for those apps across the repository this is crucial for distinguishing between different jobs when specifying rules.

after this you can add or modify your rule conditions :

```
  .change-only:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master" && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE != "schedule" && $CI_JOB_NAME == "my_unique_app"
```

create a scheduled pipeline, but set the branch to master. Since the rule in your .gitlab-ci.yml file now includes the condition $CI_JOB_NAME == "my_unique_app", only the job named my_unique_app will be triggered by the scheduled pipeline, and the rest of the jobs in other .gitlab-ci.yml files won't be affected.

Try this it will ensure that only the specific job you want to run at a particular time gets triggered by the scheduled pipeline, while the rest remain unaffected.

Comment: Is CI_JOB_NAME a variable that I need to define when creating that schedule? The docs for Gitlab just say that this predefined variable is "The name of the job". So I presume it's the name of the app in the monorepo? Is it the root-level entry at the top of the .gitlab-ci.yml file?